# Computing the covariance of a solution to the stochastic heat equation. A question concerning the notes on SPDE' s of Hairer

Tags: proof-verification, stochastic-pde

In the notes ["Introduction to Stochastic PDE's"](http://www.hairer.org/notes/SPDEs.pdf) from Martin Hairer, one reads:

> **2.3.2 A formal calculation**
>
> Define the covariance for the solution to the stochastic heat eqaution by $$C(s,t,xy)=\mathbf{E}u(s,x)u(t,y),\tag{2.7}$$ where $u$ is given by $(2.6)$.
>
> $\ \ $ By (statistical) translation invariance, it is clear that $C(s,t,x,y)=C(s,t,0,x-y)$. Using $(2.6)$ and the expression for the covariance of $\xi$, one has $$\begin{align}C(s,t,& 0,x)\\ &=\frac 1{(4\pi)^n}\mathbf{E}\int_0^t\int_0^s\int_{\mathbf{R}^n}\int_{\mathbf{R}^n}\frac1{|s-r'|^{n/2}|t-r|^{n/2}}e^{-\frac{|x-y|^2}{4(t-r)}-\frac{|y'|^2}{4(s-r')}}\xi(r,y)\xi(r',y')\,dy\,dy'\,dr'\,dr \\ 
> & = \frac1{(4\pi)^n}\int_0^{s\wedge t}\int_{\mathbf{R}^n}\frac1{|s-r|^{n/2}|t-r|^{n/2}}e^{-\frac{|x-y|^2}{4(t-r)}-\frac{|y'|^2}{4(s-r')}}\,dy\,dr \\ 
> &=\frac1{(4\pi)^n}\int_0^{s\wedge t}\int_{\mathbf{R}^n}\frac1{|s-r|^{n/2}|t-r|^{n/2}}\\ 
> &\qquad\times \exp\left(-\frac{|x|^2}{4(t-r)}-\frac{\langle x,y\rangle}{2(t-r)}-\frac{|y|^2}{4(s-r)}-\frac{|y|^2}{4(t-r)}\right)\,dy\,dr.\end{align}$$ The integral over $y$ can be performed explicitly by 'completing the square' and one obtains $$\begin{align}C(s,t,0,x)&=2^{-n}\int_0^{s\wedge t}(s+t-2r)^{-n/2}\exp\left(-\frac{|x|^2}{4(s+t-2r)}\right)\,dr\\ &=2^{-(n+1)}\int_{|s-t|}^{s+t}\ell^{-n/2}\exp\left(-\frac{|x|^2}{4\ell}\right)\,d\ell.\tag{2.8} \end{align}$$

I am trying to compute the covariance $C(s,t,0,x)$
I understand up to 
$$C(s,t,0,x) = \frac{1}{(4\pi)^n}\int_0^{s\wedge t} \int_{\Bbb{R}^n}\frac{1}{|s-r|^{n/2}|t-r|^{n/2}} e^{-\frac{|x-y|^2}{4(t-r)}}e^{-\frac{|y|^2}{4(s-r)}}dy dr$$
Now we write $|x-y|^2 = |x|^2 - 2\langle x,y\rangle + |y|^2$ then we should obtain

$$ C(s,t,0,x) = \frac{1}{(4\pi)^n}\int_0^{s\wedge t} \int_{\Bbb{R}^n}\frac{1}{|s-r|^{n/2}|t-r|^{n/2}} \\
\times \exp\bigg(-\frac{|x|^2}{4(t-r)} + \frac{ \langle x,y\rangle}{2(t-r)}-\frac{|y|^2}{4(s-r)}-\frac{ |y|^2}{4(t-r)}\bigg)dy dr$$

So you see a sign difference here (Is this a typo?)

Moving on to completing the square we obtain

$$\bigg( \frac{ \langle x,y\rangle}{2(t-r)}-\frac{|y|^2}{4(s-r)}-\frac{ |y|^2}{4(t-r)}\bigg) \\
=\bigg(-\frac{(t+s-2r)}{4(s-r)(t-r)}|y|^2 + \frac{ \langle x,y\rangle}{2(t-r)}\bigg) \\
=\bigg(-\frac{(t+s-2r)}{4(s-r)(t-r)}\bigg[|y|^2 + \frac{2(s-r) \langle x,y\rangle }{(t + s -2r)}\bigg]\bigg) \\
=\bigg(-\frac{(t+s-2r)}{4(s-r)(t-r)}\bigg[\bigg|y - \frac{(s-r) x }{(t + s -2r)}\bigg|^2 - \frac{(s-r)^2  |x|^2 }{(t + s -2r)^2}\bigg]\bigg) \\
=\exp\bigg(\frac{(s-r)  |x|^2 }{4(t + s -2r) (t-r)}\bigg) \exp\bigg( -\frac{(t+s-2r)}{4(s-r)(t-r)}\bigg|y - \frac{(s-r) x }{(t + s -2r)}\bigg|^2\bigg)
$$

Combining this with the term $\frac{|x|^2}{4(t-r)}$  and ignoring the other terms in the integral we obtain
$$ \exp\bigg(\frac{(s-r)  |x|^2 }{4(t + s -2r) (t-r)}-\frac{|x|^2}{4(t-r)}\bigg)\\
\exp\bigg(\frac{(s-r)  |x|^2  -|x|^2 (t + s -2r)}{4(t + s -2r) (t-r)}\bigg)\\
\exp\bigg(\frac{ -|x|^2 (t -r)}{4(t + s -2r) (t-r)}\bigg)\\
\exp\bigg(\frac{ -|x|^2 }{4(t + s -2r)}\bigg)\\
$$
It remains to compute the integral

$$\int_{\Bbb{R}^n}\exp\bigg(-\frac{(t+s-2r)}{4(s-r)(t-r)} \bigg|y - \frac{(s-r) x }{(t + s -2r)}\bigg|^2\bigg)\, dy  \\
=\int_{\Bbb{R}^n}\exp\bigg( -\frac{(t+s-2r)}{4(s-r)(t-r)}|y|^2\bigg)\, dy\\ 
=\bigg(\frac{4\pi(s-r)(t-r)}{(t+s-2r)}\bigg)^{-n/2}$$

Putting this together we arrive at

$$C(s,t,0,x) = \frac{1}{(4\pi)^n} (4\pi)^{-n/2} \int_0^{s\wedge t} \bigg(\frac{1}{(t+s-2r)}\bigg)^{-n/2}\exp\bigg(\frac{-|x|^2}{4(t + s -2r)}\bigg) dr \\ =  \frac{1}{(\pi)^{n/2}|} \frac{1}{2^{n+1}}\int_{|s-t|}^{s+t} \bigg(\frac{1}{\ell}\bigg)^{-n/2}\exp\bigg(\frac{ -|x|^2 }{4\ell}\bigg) d\ell$$

So there is a constant $\pi^{-n/2}$ that appeared in my computation, but not in the notes.

Is this a typo?

Also, one reads

By (statistical) translation invariance, it is clear that $C(s,t,x,y)= C(s,t,0,x-y)$.

Instead, shouldn't it be $C(s,t,x,y)= C(s,t,0,y-x)$?